startActivityForResult is deprecated, How to use registerForActivityResult in Flutter Plugin
I am the author of a Flutter Plugin that currenlty uses the startActivityForResult.
Since it was deprecated, and Google highly recommends the new StartActivityForResult API I would like to switch to the new registerForActivityResult.
However, the current approach requires  changing FlutterActivity to FlutterFragmentActivity https://stackoverflow.com/a/79201420/6727914
This is fine for personal projects, but since I am developing a published plugin, does this mean that I should add in the installation documentation of my plugin that this step needs to be done ?
This would be a breaking change since  the plugin used to worked without needing any change one the Android file, with the current deprecated API.
Is there a way to make it work without requiring the developer to make any manual change to their Android Kotlin file ?

Note that "deprecated" in this case means "we have a better solution that we would like for you to consider". Under the covers, the new solution uses the "deprecated" startActivityForResult(). Particularly for a plugin like yours, there may not be enough advantages for using the new solution compared to just continuing to use what you have.
